# A hypothesis test that conditional expectation (i.e. regression line) is above some number in a region of the factor space

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, logistic, generalized-linear-model, point-estimation

In my work we want to know whether some variable of interest satisfies some threshold. Maybe imagine that we ask questions like whether a widget has *at least* a 60% probability of functioning. Realistically, whether the widget functions or not depends on certain factors, and if one wants to understand the widget's performance they should design an experiment in which those factors are varied and a model, such as a logistic regression model, is built. The usual tests that computer programs give you when making a regression model tell you which factors of the model are statistically significant or not. But we don't necessarily care whether a factor has an effect or not; if the widget meets the threshold, we're indifferent to whether a factor has an effect on conditional mean. Granted, if we have a continuous factor and a factor had a nonzero effect, there could be regions where the threshold is exceeded if only because a non-constant line spans all real numbers, so we should instead focus on some region of interest and not the entire plane, and ask whether the threshold is met in that region.

So how would one test whether in some region a threshold is met? How could I test whether over an entire region of interest in the factor space, the widget functions with a probability of at least 60%?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "factor space"?  One might imagine you mean the set of possible values of all explanatory variables--but in that case your question is unanswerable, because (by design) the probability varies according to the factor values.  That complicates the interpretation of what you mean by "at least 60%."  Would that mean, for instance, that the widget functions with 60% probability at *all* values in the region of interest, at *at least one* such value, or perhaps even *on average* after you specify a probability distribution over that region?

Comment: @whuber The factor space is the possible values of the factors being controlled. For example, for the widget, the factors might be room temperature (real valued) and operating mode (discrete, maybe three modes), and the factor space would be all combinations of temperature and mode.

It's possible that mathematically the factor space is really big, perhaps because one factor is unbounded and real-valued (like temperature), so instead worry only about temperatures between 20 and 30 degrees C, and all operating mode. Is the minimum probability of function at least 60% in this space?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "minimum probability of function."  It is important that you describe this carefully and quantitatively, because there are many possible interpretations having different solutions.

Comment: @whuber You observe a widget, and the widget either functions or does not function. The response variable is Bernoulli, yes/no. You do some experiments and fit a logistic regression model to this yes/no response variable. The model estimates the probability the widget functions for a given combination of factors. Is the smallest of these probabilities at least 60% for all combinations of factors of interest?

Comment: That's now clear. But it doesn't require a statistical test: it requires only some way to find the minimum of the predicted value over a given set of factors. How to do that efficiently depends on how the factors are introduced in the model. For instance, when the model is additive in them all, the minimum can be found instantly by examining the signs of the estimated coefficients to determine the point at which the minimum occurs and evaluating the prediction there.  What would require some *statistical* analysis would be if you wanted to know the level of confidence in this determination.